# PLSQL to PIGLATIN

Tags: apache-pig

```
select (WHEN tt.trxn = 'P' AND ip.crdate = dtd.podate 

        THEN
             dtd.A || dtdB || dtd.C 
        ELSE
             NULL
             END) XXXX,..
```

is my plsql script.

I am using case condition.

```
T = LOAD '//transaction_types' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,trxn:chararray);

D = LOAD '/home/sterlingpc1/Desktop/det_trades' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,id1:int,A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray,pdate:chararray);

I = LOAD '//transaction_types' USING PigStorage(',') as (id1:int,cdate:chararray);

JOINED = JOIN T by id,D by id;
JOINED1 = JOIN JOINED by id1,I by id1;
b = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case 
                       WHEN T::trxn == 'P' AND
                     I::cdate == dtd::pdate
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                   NULL
                       END)
```

It throws exception.

How to give or check  more than one condition(`FOR tt.trxn = 'P' AND ip.crdate = dtd.podate` ) in CASE STATEMENT at PIG Latin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PLSQL to PIG Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860944/plsql-to-pig-conversion)

Comment: @Andrew : Can you share sample input data for ip, D and T ? We can join multiple aliases in a single go : joined = JOIN T BY id, IP BY id,  D BY id;

Comment: @Andrew : ip alias is missing in the above code snippet. I believe one of the T alias in the script is ip alias.

Comment: @Murali Rao : Sorry. there is no common column for the three tables. So only i have joined first two tables with id  and then another one with another same column id1.

Comment: The conditions i need to check in the case condition also from three various tables. That's why  i have joined the three tables in to one. but shows error.                                                       Table T and D are has id as a common field. Table D and I has id1 as the same column. How to to join this type of tables.

Comment: JOINED = JOIN T by id,D by id;                                                                                             b = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE          
                  (case 
                       WHEN T::trxn == 'P'                                                                                  THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                   NULL
                       END)

Comment: this works correctly. But joining the third table and adding the second condition in case it throws error.

Comment: I got solution .. but not my exact output. please check my answer part.

Comment: I got a solution. But checking both condition using AND i cant get any output.only NULL which means else part is executing. I am near to the answer. I need to check both condition using and and then conacat it. Please check my plsql query. Give me an idea.b2 = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case 
                     WHEN T::trxn == 'P' OR
                     I::cdate == D::pdate
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE  NULL
                       END);
dump b2
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AAABBBCCC)

Comment: @MuraliRao: i have given the sampl table in my answer. But did not get correct answer. Till now need another solution.\

Answer (score 0):

## tab.T

01,p
02,p
03,p

## tab.D

01,AA,BB,CC,ASDF
02,AAA,BBB,CCC,ASDF
03,AA,BB,CC,ASDF

## tab.I

01,AA,ASDF
02,AAA,ASDF
03,AA,ASDF

T = LOAD '/home/sterlingpc1/Documents/TEST/T' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,trxn:chararray);

D = LOAD '/home/sterlingpc1/Documents/TEST/D' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray,pdate:chararray);

I = LOAD '/home/sterlingpc1/Documents/TEST/I' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,A:chararray,cdate:chararray);

JOINED = JOIN T by id,D by id;

JOINED1 = JOIN JOINED by A,I by A;

b = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case 
                       WHEN T::trxn == 'p' 
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                       NULL
                       END);

## dump b

(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AAABBBCCC)

b1 = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case WHEN 
                       I::cdate == D::pdate
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                       NULL
                       END);

## dump b1

(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AAABBBCCC)

b2 = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case 
                     WHEN T::trxn == 'p' OR
                     I::cdate == D::pdate
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                       NULL
                       END);

## dump b2

(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AAABBBCCC)

b2 = FOREACH JOINED1 GENERATE 
                  (case 
                     WHEN T::trxn == 'p' AND
                     I::cdate == D::pdate
                       THEN
                       CONCAT(D::A,D::B,D::C)
                       ELSE
                       NULL
                       END);

## dump b2

(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AABBCC)
(AAABBBCCC)

I got a solution. I just change the condition. For small 'p' i put 'P'. Thats the mistake. Now i got expected output friends. Thanks a lot!